# SFINAE in a template class

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015, sfinae, enable-if

I'm trying to figure out if Clang 3.4 allows something that is ill formed while MSVS2015 is more precise or if it's just a matter of changing the synax.

I wrote the following code:

#### Header

```
template<typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
  template<typename U> using for_bar = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U,Bar>::value>;
  template<typename U> using for_baz = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<U,Bar>::value>;

  template<typename U = T> typename for_bar<U>::type postUpdate();
  template<typename U = T> typename for_baz<U>::type postUpdate();
};
```

#### Source

```
template<typename T>
template<typename U> typename Foo<T>::template for_baz<U>::type Foo<T>::postUpdate()
{
  // code
}

template<typename T>
template<typename U> typename Foo<T>::template for_bar<U>::type Foo<T>::postUpdate()
{
  // code
}
```

This compiles and works fine on Clang 3.4 (OSX 10.8.5). Basically SFINAE is used directly on the class template using a template of template method.

But the code refuses to work on MSVC2015 with the following error:

```
error C2244: 'Foo<T>::postUpdate': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
note: see declaration of 'Foo<T>::postUpdate'
note: definition
note: 'for_baz<U>::type Foo<T>::postUpdate(void)'
note: existing declarations
note: 'enable_if<!std::is_same<U,Baz>::value,void>::type Foo<T>::postUpdate(void)'
note: 'enable_if<std::is_same<U,Baz>::value,void>::type Foo<T>::postUpdate(void)'
```

I'm totally not practical with MSVC diagnostics so I don't know what to look for, according to the error I would think that SFINAE is not working as intended but I'm not sure, since this works fine on another compiler.

#### EDIT:

Actually if the method is defined inline then the code seems to compile correctly so there must be something related to the definition which is not correctly matched to the declaration.

Comment: MSVC seems not to handle disambiguation correctly.
If you remove `template` disambiguation like
`template<typename T>
template<typename U> typename Foo<T>::for_baz<U>::type Foo<T>::postUpdate()
{ ... }`
, the code might compile.

Comment: @IseWisteria: by removing the `using` type alias and embedding the `enable_if` directly in the template it compiles, eg `template<typename U = T, typename std::enable_if<..., int> = 0> void postUpdate()`. Now I wonder if clang accepts something that is correct for the standard or MSVC is lacking compatibility.

Comment: Changing `for_bar` to `typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, Bar>::value>::type` and adjusting everything else accordingly makes it work fine. I don't see any reason for your version not to compile. This looks like an MSVC bug. I could add a simplified version of your example to a [somewhat related bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1989695/vc-14-update-1-rc-friend-function-template-declaration-rejected-when-alias-template-is-used-in-template-parameter) that I filed.